# tablesgenerator generates an couple of errors

Tags: tables

I used "tablesgenerator.com" to generte a table. Unfortunately, I am getting a couple of errors and I can't remember how to fix them.

Hope someone will lend a hand. If you do so please write a explanation of alterations.

#### Minimal (not) working example

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,siunitx,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Primer-name & Type                                    & Description                                                               \\
U1          & 5'-ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3'              & Amplify w. D2 whole ayg1 gene-region - forward                       \\
U2          & 5'-GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3'              & Together with 188 amplifies bipartite fragment downstream - reverse  \\
U1a         & 5’-GGTCTTAAU ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3’    & Amplify w. U2a upstream fragment w. Uracil tail - forward            \\
U2b         & 5’-GGCATTAAU GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3     & Amplify w. U1b upstream fragment w. Uracil tail - reverse            \\
D1          & 5’-CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3'            & Amplify w. U1 whole ayg1 gene- region - forward                       \\
D2          & 5’-ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3'            & Together with 187 amplifies bipartite fragment upstream - forward    \\
D1c         & 5’-GGACTTAAU CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3'  & Amplify w. D2d downstream fragment w. Uracil tail - forward          \\
D2d         & 5’-GGGTTTAAU ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3'  & Amplify w. D1c downstream fragment w. Uracil tail - reverse          \\
188         & 5'-AATACGAGGTCGCCAACATC-3'              & Together with U1 amplifies bipartite fragment downstream - reverse   \\
187         & 5'-ATAGGTCAGGCTCTCGCTGA-3'              & Together with U2 amplifies bipartite fragment upstream - forward     \\
139         & 5'-ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3'              & Sequencing primer upstream fragment, first 700bp - forward           \\
140         & 5'-GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3'              & Sequencing primer upstream fragment, last 700bp - reverse            \\
141         & 5’-CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3'            & Sequencing primer downstream fragment, first 700bp - forward         \\
142         & 5’-ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3'            & Sequencing primer downstream fragment, last 700bp - reverse          \\
V1-fwd      & 5´-TATTTGTCTGGATCGACGCCC-3'             & Amplify w. V2-rev whole hph cassette + up/downstream- forward        \\
V1-rev      & 5´-TCACTGGCAAACTGTGATGGA-3'             & Amplify w. V1-fwd upstream bipartite- forward                        \\
V2-fwd      & 5´-TCGTCCATCACAGTTTGCCA-3'              & Amplify w. V2-rev downstream bipartite- forward                      \\
V2-rev      & 5´-GCAAGCCTACAAATGAGCCG-3'              & Amplify w. V1-fwd whole hph cassette + up/downstream- reverse         
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How could we help you if you didn't show the errors?!

Comment: The method to find the root cause would be to narrow down which line(s) are causing the errors, and which ones are irrelevant. One method is [code bisection](https://www.nics.utk.edu/faq/darter-how-do-i-use-code-bisection-method-find-bug): comment out half the table rows and see if the compile works, then start repeatedly uncommenting half of the remaining lines and recompiling. I've done it, and you'll find there are four failing rows in the table, due to copying and pasting three different types of prime symbols (`'`, `’`, and `´`), only two of which are compatible with your packages.

Comment: unrelated to the error but don't use `[h]` It usually generates a warning and latex changes it to `[ht]` don't use `\resizebox` on tables it just generates inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to incorporate an answer. Now the code as posted genrates no errors so neither the question nor the answer make any sense to people reading the site. `$\prime$` is in anycase the incorrect fix, but even if it is correct the correct code should be in the _answer_ not the question.

Comment: OK so now you've edited it again so it generates a new error totally unrelated to the original question. Please don't do that. You forgot the `\\ ` before `\bottonmrule`

Comment: @Strangelove you have specified a two column document, but then forced the table using `\resizebox` to be `\textwidth` wide so more than twice the width of a column, do you intend the table to fit in a column, in which case a different layout is needed, or do you intend it to span both coulns in which case you need `table*` not `table` and you can not use `h`.

Answer (score 4):

The error you get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textasciiacute
```

which you can define by loading `textcomp` package but I suspect you do not want to do that.

The markup you have is highly inconsistent,

Some rows have

```
5'
```

some have

```
5'
```

some have

```
5´
```

That is apostrophe, right single quote and acute accent. It is the third of these (just used on the last few rows of the table) that generates the error.

But did you really intend them to be different?

Comment: No that was a mistake, from excel - a have changed all apostrophes to \prime which should be correct

Comment: @Strangelove no `\prine` is wrong (and will generate an error that you are not in math mode) you should just use `'` that is a normal ascii apostrophe,

Comment: okay, i just tried to add \bottomrule but it gives an error - can you tell me why ?

Comment: @Strangelove presumably you added it in the wrong place, if you don't show the code or the error hard to guess (but it is not related to this question and the site format doesn't really encourage asking new questions in comments, best to ask questions as new questions)

Comment: You're missing a row-break instruction before `\bottomrule`.

Comment: @David Carlisle , i attempted to clean up the thread. Do you have any suggestions as to how the table could look better ?

Answer (score 0):

FIXES. 
initial error was ! Undefined control sequence.
 \textasciiacute

As pointed out by @David Carlisle it was due to inconsistent use of apostrophe, initially this was fixed using $\prime$ which should have been $^\prime$ however finally fixed by consistently use of $'$ a normal ascii apostrophe - also pointed out by  @Mike Renfro, @David Carlisle and @egreg

\toprule , \midrule , \bottomrule was also added. Note row-break was needed before \bottomrule. - thanks @Mico

Multicolumn was also added to center titles

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,siunitx,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Oligonucleotides used in this study}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primer-name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Type}                &     \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}                                                                                                             \\   
\midrule
U1          & 5$'$-ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3$'$            & Amplify w. D2 whole ayg1 gene-region - forward                       \\
U2          & 5$'$-GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3$'$            & Together with 188 amplifies bipartite fragment downstream - reverse  \\
U1a         & 5$'$-GGTCTTAAU ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3$'$  & Amplify w. U2a upstream fragment w. Uracil tail - forward            \\
U2b         & 5$'$-GGCATTAAU GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3$'$  & Amplify w. U1b upstream fragment w. Uracil tail - reverse            \\
D1          & 5$'$-CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3$'$          & Amplify w. U1 whole ayg1 gene-region - forward                       \\
D2          & 5$'$-ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3$'$          & Together with 187 amplifies bipartite fragment upstream - forward    \\
D1c         & 5$'$-GGACTTAAU CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3$'$& Amplify w. D2d downstream fragment w. Uracil tail - forward          \\
D2d         & 5$'$-GGGTTTAAU ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3$'$& Amplify w. D1c downstream fragment w. Uracil tail - reverse          \\
188         & 5$'$-AATACGAGGTCGCCAACATC-3$'$            & Together with U1 amplifies bipartite fragment downstream - reverse   \\
187         & 5$'$-ATAGGTCAGGCTCTCGCTGA-3$'$            & Together with U2 amplifies bipartite fragment upstream - forward     \\
139         & 5$'$-ACGGATAGCCAAGTAGGGAG-3$'$            & Sequencing primer upstream fragment, first 700bp - forward           \\
140         & 5$'$-GGGCAAATGGGGGAGCAAGA-3$'$            & Sequencing primer upstream fragment, last 700bp - reverse            \\
141         & 5$'$-CCCACTCAGCTACCACAAATAC-3$'$          & Sequencing primer downstream fragment, first 700bp - forward         \\
142         & 5$'$-ACCATCACTAACTCTTCTCCAC-3$'$          & Sequencing primer downstream fragment, last 700bp - reverse          \\
V1-fwd      & 5$'$-TATTTGTCTGGATCGACGCCC-3$'$           & Amplify w. V2-rev whole hph cassette + up/downstream- forward        \\
V1-rev      & 5$'$-TCACTGGCAAACTGTGATGGA-3$'$           & Amplify w. V1-fwd upstream bipartite- forward                        \\
V2-fwd      & 5$'$-TCGTCCATCACAGTTTGCCA-3$'$            & Amplify w. V2-rev downstream bipartite- forward                      \\
V2-rev      & 5$'$-GCAAGCCTACAAATGAGCCG-3$'$            & Amplify w. V1-fwd whole hph cassette + up/downstream- reverse        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\label{tab:primertable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `$\prime$` is wrong; use `$'$` instead or, if you prefer, `$^\prime$`: look at the output to see why.

Comment: This generates overfull box warnings as a `\textwidth` wide table can not fit in a column that is less than half that width.